# Reference error Sfjs is not defined

Tags: symfony, assetic

I just started  with symfony, on template I simply define:

```
{% javascripts "@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/app.js" %}
    <script src="{{asset_url}}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

right before closing body tag `</body>`.

I get this javascript error:

> ReferenceError: Sfjs is not defined

It seems like my javascript is affecting symfony debugbar script. but its happen even when my `app.js` contains nothing. How should I fix this ? thanks.

Answer (score 27):

Although this is an old topic with an already found untold solution, I just wanted to share my experience that when I was confronted with the same error, it was due to the fact that I had forgotten to add a closing `</script>` tag somewhere in my base template.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to Symfony myself, but I believe you need to put spaces between the brackets and the variable. In other words, the second line should look like this:

```
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
```

That should help Symfony find the script, which will allow the toolbar to show up.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have added a style sheet that interfered with JS. Not sure how or why TBH.

```
<style rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css"/>
```